# python json object_pairs_hook dictionary decoded to None

Tags: python, json, dictionary, decode, json-deserialization

I've stumbled upon a very surprising observation when working with the python standard `json` library, and more specifically when using `object_pairs_hook` from there.

Here's my data:

```
items.json:
--
{
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
}
--
```

And here's my minimum working code:

```
Jupyter QtConsole 4.3.1
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

import json

def dummy_hook(input):
    print("INPUT:",input)


filename = r'items.json'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f,object_pairs_hook=dummy_hook)
```

Surprisingly (to me), the outcome is this:

```
INPUT: [('value', 'New'), ('onclick', 'CreateNewDoc()')]
INPUT: [('value', 'Open'), ('onclick', 'OpenDoc()')]
INPUT: [('value', 'Close'), ('onclick', 'CloseDoc()')]
INPUT: [('menuitem', [None, None, None])]
```

In particular, you will realize that the three dictionaries with the "value"/"onclick" pairs have been decoded to `None`. This is a problem for me, as I have been hoping to perform some further operations on these.

Questions: Is this to be expected? Am I doing something incorrectly here?

EDIT:
So changing the hook function into:

```
def dummy_hook(input):
    print("INPUT:",input)
    return 7
```

Does indeed change the print outcome into:

```
INPUT: [('value', 'New'), ('onclick', 'CreateNewDoc()')]
INPUT: [('value', 'Open'), ('onclick', 'OpenDoc()')]
INPUT: [('value', 'Close'), ('onclick', 'CloseDoc()')]
INPUT: [('menuitem', [7,7,7])]
```

How adding a `return` statement changes the decoding outcome, I still don't understand. But yes, in principle, this solves the problem.

Comment: You need to return something from `dummy_hook()`

Comment: `dummy_hook` returns `None`, yes, this is expected behavior.

Comment: The question is not that much about what does the `dummy_hook` return, as this is probably clear from the function definition, as much as it is about why a list of dictionaries from the original `json` file gets decoded into a list of `None`'s, and why adding a return statement in the `dummy_hook` changes this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what you don't understand. The result of the function is used as the value of the decoded object. Your first function returned `None` always, and the second returns `7` always.... this objects will get decoded as `None` and 7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function `dummy_hook` should return a value. In your case, maybe the same input.

> object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. **The return value of object_pairs_hook will be used instead of the dict.** This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example, collections.OrderedDict() will remember the order of insertion). If object_hook is also defined, the object_pairs_hook takes priority.

from: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: I still don't understand why, but yes, this solved this.